# Trying to download an image file and I keep getting a file saying "Image Not Available"

Tags: python

I'm trying to download book cover images from Google Books API. It ends up giving me a link like this:

http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Tum3dwFzSngC&printsec=frontcover&img=1

If you click on it, you can see it loads and is there. So then, I just use this code to download the image:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Tum3dwFzSngC&printsec=frontcover&img=1')
with open('test.jpeg', "wb") as f:      
    f.write(r.content)
    f.close()
```

But, the image I get from this is always just a 9kb file that says "Image Not Available" which I'm assuming just comes from the API when a requested image isn't there. Am I doing something wrong here? It seems pretty standard and simple so I'm unsure what wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The server does not want to answer you since it sees the request is not coming from a browser - a common practice. For example, I opened the image in Chrome and copied the request Chrome sent as a CURL request and it worked. Sending simply:

```
curl 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Tum3dwFzSngC&printsec=frontcover&img=1'
```

Does not.

The server is checking for a User Agent. If a valid one is not found, it does not send the image. You can [easily fake a user agent](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/user_agent.html), or use something like [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to emulate a browser. A simple example of a CURL request that saves the response to an`img.jpg` is:

```
curl 'http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Tum3dwFzSngC&printsec=frontcover&img=1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36' >> img.jpg
```

Comment: I added the user agent to the request and it still downloaded the same 'not available' file.

Comment: Did you try the CURL request I included? It's a very basic request and it works. Are you sure the user agent has been added properly? Can you update your post with the code used to define the UA?

Comment: I used this:
`header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Tum3dwFzSngC&printsec=frontcover&img=1', headers=header)`

and i tried the curl and that still gave me the same not available image.

Comment: You tried the CURL exactly as I typed it and it still gave the same result? Did you check the result in `img.jpg`?

Comment: Yep, I copied the curl command (only changed the single quotes to normal quotes) , ran it then opened `img.jpg` it made and it showed the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure, then. It works in my shell, so I'm unable to replicate the problem.